# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when reading from string

Tags: java, android

In my project I want to read from string my package name but I got following error.
before I change may code it was like that:

```
static {
    sURLMatcher.addURI("com.nooshindroid.yastashir2.model", "alarm", ALARMS);
    sURLMatcher.addURI("com.nooshindroid.yastashir2.model", "alarm/#", ALARMS_ID);
}
```

In my application class I  get the like this:

```
 public static String context;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    context = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.package_app);
 }
```

and when I change it like this :

```
  static {
    sURLMatcher.addURI(AlarmApplication.context+".model", "alarm", ALARMS);
    sURLMatcher.addURI(AlarmApplication.context+".model", "alarm/#", ALARMS_ID);
}
```

and here is my error:

```
Unable to create application com.nooshindroid.yastashir2.AlarmApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.nooshindroid.yastashir2.model/alarm
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4809)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in the `static` initialisation block runs before your `Application`'s `onCreate`. So your `context` field is still `null` when you add URIs to the matcher.

Can you maybe instead use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".model"` in your static initialisation? `BuildConfig` fields are written at build time, so will be available in the static initialisation block. If `APPLICATION_ID` doesn't suit your needs, you can always add a custom build config field in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: That's right. I use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID and it works nice. thanks a lot...

Comment: When you find an answer that is useful you should upvote it. And if it's an answer to a question you asked and it solves your problem then you should also accept it. This way if someone has the same problem and finds this page, they will know that this answer works.